# Make Input Suggestion Controls move with Input

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, input

Hopefully, that title makes sense to what's occurring.

I have a [CodeSandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7qyxkn511?fontsize=14) here for you all to have a look.

I have a div that gets hidden when a user focuses on an input.

When this occurs (for me at least), The input goes to the top of the parent div and but the browser suggested input element (in this case, email address) sticks to where the element used to be.

Is it possible to adjust the suggestion element in any way so that it follows the position of the input?

[image: Incorrect Position of Input Suggestions]

Comment: i cannot see any suggestion box

Comment: @XenioGracias This is just happening to me in Chrome, if that helps?

Comment: You are making the height to be 0. Why dont you keep it to its original height?

Comment: @Mani Not my decision, in the actually application, there is content there that needs to be hidden completely, including it's height so the form takes its place.

Comment: you don't want the input to go on top??

Comment: @mcclosa It happens on IE and other browsers also. Please state what help you want.

Comment: @XenioGracias, No, I do want it. I thought the reference the Mani made with the height being 0 was to keep the divs height, but I do not, the transition there currently is how it is supposed to be. The help I want it whether it was possible to have the suggestion element move along with the input

Comment: @mcclosa where is the suggestion element??.. how to make it visible

Comment: You can see it in the screenshot above. Because I use Chrome regularly, I have suggested email addresses because it is an email input, so it seems to have saved suggestions based upon the previous emails I have entered successfully into an email input. Perhaps if I add a submit button it will save the email address in your suggestions too?

Comment: It looks like this? I thought this was very common across browsers to suggest autocompletion?? http://code.stylenet.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/01.png

Answer (score 0):

CSS:
Put input and suggestion box in container, then set position of suggestion box relatively or absolutely to container.

JS:
Calculate position of input then set position of suggestion box using that data.

Comment: I cannot select the suggestion box, it is not really part of the DOM, as in, it doesn't have a class selector to define in CSS